# D3 bar chart on MouseMove display Y value

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

I have included my R code and my D3JS code. I'm trying to create a normal distribution in R-Studio, and using D3 to visualize the results, the R code is as follows, and was created to be replicable. I want the MouseMove code to show the Y-axis value on MouseMove, but currently it's not working. Any tips is appreciated.

Happy Thanksgiving!

```html
library(r2d3)
# Generate standard normal distribution data
set.seed(123)
df <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
# Bin the data to create a histogram
binned_df <- hist(df, plot = FALSE, breaks = 770)
# Convert the binned data to a data frame
df <- data.frame(mid = binned_df$mids, count = binned_df$counts)
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "df")) # Clear enviroment
# Use r2d3 to pass the data to D3.js
r2d3(data = df, script = "~/Desktop/D3Test.js")
```

The D3 code is:

```js
// D3 code to create an interactive histogram with varying shades of blue, tooltips, and bar height display on mouseover
r2d3.onRender(function(data, svg, width, height) {
  // Set margins
  var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Set the scales
  var x = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.mid;
    }));

  var y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.count;
    })]);

  // Append the svg object to the body of the page
  var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Define a color scale for varying shades of blue
  var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues)
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.count;
    })]);

  // Create a tooltip
  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  // Add the bars
  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.mid);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.count);
    })
    .attr("width", 10) // fixed width for each bar
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.count);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.count); // Vary shades of blue based on count
    })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove) // Updated mousemove function
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  // Tooltip functions
  function mouseover(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1);
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function mousemove(d) {
  const tooltipContent = `Value: ${d.count}<br>Mid: ${d.mid}`;
  tooltip
    .html(tooltipContent)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px") // Adjust the left offset as needed
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); // Adjust the top offset as needed

  // Add text for bar height at the top of the bar
  const barHeightText = g.selectAll(".bar-height-text").data([d]);
  barHeightText
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "bar-height-text")
    .attr("x", x(d.mid) + 5) // Adjust the positioning as needed
    .attr("y", y(d.count) - 5) // Adjust the positioning as needed
    .text(`Height: ${d.count}`)
    .style("fill", "black");

  barHeightText
    .merge(barHeightText) // Update existing text
    .text(`Height: ${d.count}`);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  function mouseout(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0);
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.7);
  }

  // Add the x-axis
  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the y-axis
  g.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Append text labels and arrows to the x-axis
  var xAxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  xAxis.append("text")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", 30) // Adjust the y-coordinate for vertical positioning
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("More Conservative");

  xAxis.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 30) // Adjust the y-coordinate for vertical positioning
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("More Liberal");

  // Append arrows (optional)
  var arrowSize = 10;
  xAxis.append("polygon")
    .attr("points", "0,0 " + arrowSize + ",0 " + arrowSize / 2 + "," + arrowSize)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (arrowSize + 25) + ")")
    .style("fill", "black"); // Adjust arrow styling as needed

  xAxis.append("polygon")
    .attr("points", "0,0 -" + arrowSize + ",0 -" + arrowSize / 2 + "," + arrowSize)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", " + (arrowSize + 25) + ")")
    .style("fill", "black"); // Adjust arrow styling as needed
});
```